# How do I "encode" a dataframe's column from pandas

Tags: pandas, replace

df_data is a dataframe["diagnosis"] with a column of strings ("B" and "M") that I want to convert to 1 and 0

```
Code:

 dftest = df_data["diagnosis"].replace({"B": 1, "M": 0},
                                        inplace=True)



Error: 
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'
```

Comment: `df_data['diagnosis'].eq('B').astype(int)`

Comment: ```dftest["diagnosis"] = df_data["diagnosis"].replace({"B": 1, "M": 0})```